# Why such $\theta$ exists by replacement?

Tags: set-theory, axioms

In Jech's textbook set theory, theorem 2.27, the author is proving any well-founded relation has a height. As the picture below,
[image]

I don't understand this step. Why such $\theta$ exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the function $x\mapsto\min\{\alpha\mid x\in P_\alpha\}$. Since $P$ is a set, its image is a set of ordinals. So there is some $\theta$ which is an upper bound.

Now it is easy to see that $P_\theta=P_{\theta+1}$, since no new members could be added, we have exhausted $P$.

Comment: Thank you. But the book haven't proved that any set of ordinals has an upper bound. Does this need axiom of choice?

Comment: Not even remotely.

Comment: Also, take a look at the text right after the proof of Lemma 2.11, which precedes what you are reading now.

Comment: Thank you. Now I've understand it.

Comment: @QiRenrui If an answer has resolved your question, you can accept it by clicking the check mark on the left hand side. (Besides rewarding the answer, this has the benefit of marking the question as resolved.)